# subsampling rosbag images

Tags: ros, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I got a problem by coping with the rosbag. I want to evaluate the SLAM performance in wide baseline. I got a rosbag, which is 50fps(frame per second) . The specific task is subsample the rosbag, make the fps to 25 or 20. Is there has some ways to modify the rosbag?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229485/subsampling-rosbag-images/) by [Jingwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/26325/jingwei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is similar http://answers.ros.org/question/114291/how-to-throttle-a-bag-file/ , also look at http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/throttle .  You'd have to play the bag file into the throttle node and then re-record it into a new bag, or always play the source bag with the throttle when running with your slam nodes.

It would be nice if rosbag filter http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#filter could throttle an input into an output directly - maybe with the right filter expression?  A filter like `"m.header.stamp.nsec < 500000000" /my_image_topic` maybe could do a very crude time filtering where if there are 50 frames in one second, only the frames from the first half of the second would go into the output bag, but the output wouldn't be very smooth.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2